# Conflict after disable module sparsh/magento-2-product-label-extension

Tags: magento2

We have install module via composer:
composer require sparsh/magento-2-product-label-extension

This module is completely bugged and many functions in website have conflict.

Now I disable module - but still I have conflicts.

Step 2:
I remove via composer and upgrade etc.
composer remove sparsh/magento-2-product-label-extension

I not see now this module in vendor. But still I get the same issues (conflict):

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Sparsh\ProductLabel\Model\Config\Source\LabelOptions does not exist

Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Sparsh\ProductLabel\Model\Config\Source\LabelOptions does not exist
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php:54]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectMan
```

Impossible open product page, categories products etc.

Answer (score 4):

MOst probably you have a zombie product attribute that uses as source model the class `Sparsh\ProductLabel\Model\Config\Source\LabelOptions`.

```
SELECT * FROM eav_attribute WHERE source_model = 'Sparsh\ProductLabel\Model\Config\Source\LabelOptions'
```

Run the query above to confirm it. If it shows any results, delete them.

if it does not return any results, try with

```
SELECT * FROM eav_attribute WHERE source_model = 'Sparsh\\ProductLabel\\Model\\Config\\Source\\LabelOptions'
```